# How does extrwi work?

Tags: assembly, powerpc, opcode

I am having difficulty translating the following PowerPC instruction:

`extrwi r12, r10, 8, 16`

I have been assuming it means:

`r12 := (r10 << 24) AND 00000000000000000000000011111111`

But this doesn't seem to be right.
Can anyone verify that this is correct or not?  Thanks :)

Comment: POWER does shifts through rotates & masks. This operation *rotates* `r10` left by 24, then masks off the highest 24 bits. It results in a *right* shift & mask.

Comment: Thanks :) got shift and rotate confused

Comment: @EOF: want to write that up as an answer? looks pretty correct to me :)

Comment: @JeremyKerr: I know I'm not supposed to answer questions in the comments, but for an answer *this* short I can't be bothered. You're welcome to write an answer! Tell me when it's done so I can upvote.

Answer (score 2):

`extrwi r12, r10, 8, 16` will extract `8` bits of `r10` starting bit `16` (with bit 0 being the highest order bit (the sign bit)).

So for your question, you are almost right except that it is a *rotate* left by 24 instead of a shift left 24, then ANDing with a mask of the low 8 bits (as @EOF mentioned):

```
r12 := (r10 <rotate left by> 24) AND 00000000000000000000000011111111
```

Extract and Right Justify (Word) Immediate:

See PowerPC ISA Book I, p. 160 and explanation on p. 74:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/library/es-archguide-v2.html